# connecting to mysql using pdo shows nothing in my browser

Tags: php, mysql

I'm learning php and I have no errors showing up, but when I try to connect my php file to my mysql database rows and show it in my browser I don't see anything.

This is the code in my php file -

```
try{

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname:mytodo', 'root', '');

} catch(PDOException $e){

    die('cant connect' . $e->getMessage());

}

$statement = $pdo->prepare('select * from todos');

$statement->execute();

var_dump($statement->fetchAll());
```

There are no errors so I don't know what to do.

in my terminal my database shows this :

```
mysql> show tables;
+------------------+
| Tables_in_mytodo |
+------------------+
| todos            |
+------------------+
mysql> select * from todos;
+----+-------------+-----------+
| id | description | completed |
+----+-------------+-----------+
|  1 | nihongo genki |         1 |
|  2 | wakaru      |         0 |
+----+-------------+-----------+
```

I'm expecting to see nihongo genki and wakaru in my browser, but all I see is this array(0) { } html text printed in my browser. I'd appreciate any help with this.

Comment: always use `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` to enable exceptions your `try{}catch()` block is of no use.

Answer (score 0):

I had a typo in my string dbname:mytodo is supposed to be dbname=mytodo. After I changed that I can see my database rows in my browser.